# applying charAt method on the dom?

Tags: javascript

I have this label element with the textContent of Name On A Card, so What I want to do is that I want to change the word On to Off so how do I do that using charAt method

```
 <label for="cname" id="mylabel">Name on Card</label>
 let label=document.querySelector("label#mylabel");
 label.textContent.charAt(2)="ff";;
```

Comment: Why not just set it equal to "Off"?

Comment: charAt doesn't work like that ..

Comment: [.charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) is a getter, not a setter, you can't set a value using `charAt()`.

Comment: `document.getElmentById('mylabel').textContent = 'Name off Card'`

Comment: You can't modify the content of a string with charAt. Plus charAt represents only one character, so replacing it with two does not make sense.

Comment: Minor point of order; "Name off Card" doesn't make sense (without context)

Answer (score 1):

Use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the text content

```js
let label = document.querySelector("label#mylabel");
label.textContent = label.textContent.replace('on', 'off');
```

```html
<label for="cname" id="mylabel">Name on Card</label>
```

Or just re-write the string completely.

```js
let label = document.querySelector("label#mylabel");
label.textContent = 'Name off Card';
```

```html
<label for="cname" id="mylabel">Name on Card</label>
```

Or, as mentioned, we could add a span to the label, select the span and just replace that value.

```js
let label = document.querySelector("label#mylabel>span");
label.textContent = 'off';
```

```html
<label for="cname" id="mylabel">Name <span>on</span> Card</label>
```

Comment: But remember I didn't want it to do the whole thing I just wanted specific word.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to change just one part of a string, I would argue that that increases its importance enough to give it it's own tag for targeting.

```
<label for="cname" id="mylabel">Name <span class="operation">on</span> Card</label>

document.querySelector('#mylabel .operation').innerText = 'off';
```